# spring data neo4j @Query countQuery

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

The annotation @Query in package org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation provides certain count attributes like countQuery, countQueryName.

```
/**
 * @return simpler count-query to be executed for @{see Pageable}-support {self} will be provided by the node-id of the current entity other parameters (e.g. {name}) by the given named params
 */
String countQuery() default "";

/**
 * @return name of the named count query to be used for this annotated method, instead of Class.method.count
 */
String countQueryName() default "";
```

Can somebody please explain the usage of these? To be more specific I've written a query to fetch the posts on a topic. The query results will be paginated. The query below works fine and gives me the result.

```
@Query("start post=node:__types__(className='com.xxx.entity.Post'), topic=node({0}) match post-[:TOPIC_POST]-topic return post")
Page<Post> getPostsByTopic(Topic topic, Pageable page);
```

Now I also want the total number of results as well, do I have to write another query for this or is there a way to accommodate count query in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think countQuery should work for you, but you still need to write the count query

> If it is required that paged results return the correct total count,
>   the @Query annotation can be supplied with a count query in the
>   countQuery attribute. This query is executed separately after the
>   result query and its result is used to populate the totalCount
>   property of the returned Page.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#d0e2712

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a try. Any idea how is countQueryName/queryName used?

Comment: Both are references to external queries stored in a properties file. See section 20.8.4 in the link I posted for more info.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I had read the documentation earlier, but somehow missed this part.